# WebGL not rendering in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, webgl

I created a simple scene here http://********.net, everything works great, except that for whatever reason Firefox doesn't render my scene, even though I'm getting output from the firebug's console and no errors. The code is too long to post it on here, therefor I shared the link.

Any suggestions what could be preventing it from rendering? Thanks!

```
       Firefox 39.0
       Three.js r71
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to caniuse.com (http://caniuse.com/#search=webgl), support in Firefox for WebGL is patchy "due to the additional requirement for users to have up to date video drivers".

Indeed, I too cannot see the circular graphic in Firefox. Chrome is fine.

Comment: And here is some information on exactly what graphics drivers are required for WebGL to work in Firefox and elsewhere: https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/BlacklistsAndWhitelists